# Sql Server 2008 Full-Text Index (characters issue)

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains, full-text-indexing

The Full-Text Index searching is working perfect but suddenly I noticed that it fails when it comes to some characters variance in Arabic

In Arabic we have a trailing letter say {I} that can be written like { i } or { I } , It's the same letter but different ASCII code.. exactly like the English variance between { i } & { I }

the "Contains" function can get "ALi" but not "ALI"

- both {ALi & ALI} exist..
- {ALi} returns result but without the result of {ALI}
- {ALI} return 0 records when using full-text searching..

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you implement a different index to arabic?
You need one index to each different collation

Comment: I created the index again and dropped two options
* Accent Sensitive  -> false
* Arabic as the default language for word breaker -> removed 

It's working now, but can't tell which one fixed it..
I'd go for the first option..

Thanks a lot for your time.. Appreciate your help