# How can I pass the SQL function Replace as a parameter to full text index function Contains?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I pass the SQL function `Replace` as a parameter to full text index function `Contains`, an error occurs:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.T_PRO_ProductContents 
WHERE CONTAINS(REPLACE([Text],'e','b'), 'edara')
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This is not allowed in [the grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).

```
CONTAINS ( 
     { 
        column_name | ( column_list ) 
      | * 
      | PROPERTY ( { column_name }, 'property_name' )  
     } 
     , '<contains_search_condition>'
     [ , LANGUAGE language_term ]
   )
```

The full text index is built on the `Text` column.

Applying arbitrary functions to it means the index won't be usable.

It does not create a full text index dynamically matching your expression at run time.

The best you could do is create a computed column with formula `REPLACE([Text],'e','b')` then full text index that.

Comment: Computed column will take a large space in database because its type is varchar(max) in addition to data redundancy. the other solution is using Like operator instead of Contains but this solution make the query running slow :(

Comment: @MohamedRagab tbh I can't think of any valid use case for this anyway. Why would you globally replace all e with b?

Comment: Replace e with b is just example. i want to replace all "أ" and "إ" to "ا" and replacing another Arabic characters. i want to replace these characters and then compare with sent sql parameters

Comment: In search, if user searched by "ادارة" word. i want the search results include "ادارة" & "إدارة" & "أدارة". so all Arabic special characters should be removed before search process.

Comment: @MohamedRagab - I don't speak Arabic but is your situation the same as the questioner here? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9763650/73226 if so they added a comment indicating setting Arabic as the default word breaker and accent sensitive to false on the full text index did what they needed.

Comment: Index what you need to search for. If you need to search for non-special chars, index just the non-special chars... @MartinSmith is right, creating a computed column and indexing that is the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will open this link and I hope this includes the solution.

Comment: Thanks thepirat000, it seems to be the only solution is to create a computed column.